# Disabling checkboxes with count validation jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have few checkboxes and I want as soon as a respondent checks 3rd checkbox remaining becoming disable and viceversa. However same is not working for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/u6Lbuwwe/1/

Below is the HTML code

Below is the jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var i=0;
    $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
            $('tr td').each(function{
                if($(this).find('checkbox').is(':checked'))
                    i++;
            });
        });
        if(i==3)
            $("input:checkbox").not(':checked').prop('disabled',true);
        else
            $("input:checkbox").not(':checked').prop('disabled',false);
    });
```

please find the link below to my fiddle and suggest on mistake and corrective actions.

Comment: `$("input[type=checkbox]")`

Comment: @roullie Still not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i tried your fiddle.  add jQuery and it should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    var chkBox = $("input[type=checkbox]");
    chkBox.click(function(){
        var i = 0;
        chkBox.each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')) i++;
        });
        if(i==3)
            chkBox.not(':checked').prop('disabled',true);
        else
            chkBox.not(':checked').prop('disabled',false);  
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple and Clean**

Working Ex.

http://jsfiddle.net/3kakcxzd/2/

```
var countChecked = function() {
    var n = $('input:checked').length;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', (n===3) ? true : false);
};

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', countChecked);
```

Comment: if unchecked again all checkboxes not return enable .. check that :)